# MySQL is not inserting a backslash

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, when I try to insert a backslash into my table, it does not accept it and gives me the content without the backslash.

`id` is set to auto increment:

**Code:**

```
INSERT INTO gender (sex, date) VALUES (
'male are allowed \ female are not allowed', "2012-10-06")
```

How do I insert a literal backslash?

**Notes about escape sequences:**

```
Escape  Sequence    Character Represented by Sequence

\0     An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\'     A single quote (“'”) character.
\"     A double quote (“"”) character.
\b     A backspace character.
\n     A newline (linefeed) character.
\r     A carriage return character.
\t     A tab character.
\Z     ASCII 26 (Control+Z). See note following the table.
\\     A backslash (“\”) character.
\%     A “%” character. See note following the table.
\_     A “_” character. See note following the table.
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash :

```
INSERT INTO gender
(sex, date) VALUES (
'male are allowed \\ female are not allowed',
"2012-10-06")
```

[Reference (with the list of all characters you must escape for mysql)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

Comment: See the link I give : there are other characters that you need to escape. Be sure to read this table at least once.

Comment: @deerox: Just remember that this is non-standard behaviour. Other DBMS don't need (or use) a backslash to escape character.

Answer (score 9):

### Handle backslashes and all control characters in mysql load data infile tool:

**Step 1, create your table:**

```
mysql> create table penguin (id int primary key, chucknorris VARCHAR(4000));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**Step 2, create your file to import and put this data in there.**

```
1   spacealiens are on route
2   scramble the nimitz\
3   \its species 8472
4   \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
5   Bonus characters:!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]\|}{;'":/.?>,< anything but tab
```

**Step 3, insert into your table:**

```
mysql> load data local infile '/home/el/foo/textfile.txt' into table penguin 
       fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' 
       (@col1, @col2) set id=@col1, chucknorris=@col2;
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1
```

**Step 4, and of course, it causes this strange output:**

```
mysql> select * from penguin;
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | chucknorris                                                     |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | spacealiens are on route                                        |
|  2 | scramble the nimitz                                             |
|  3 |                                                                 |
|  4 | \\\\\\\\\                                                       |
|  5 | Bonus characters:!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]|}{;'":/.?>,< anything but tab |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Step 5, analyze the warning:**

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                |
+---------+------+------------------------------------- ------------------+
| Warning | 1262 | Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there |
|         |      | were input columns                                     |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Step 6, think about exactly what went wrong:**

The backslash to the left of `nimitz` caused the mysql load data parser to concatenate the end of line 2 with the beginning of line 3.  Then it bumped up against a tab and put 'scramble the nimitz\n3 into row 2.

The rest of row 3 is skipped because the extra words `its species 8472` do not fit anywhere, it produces the warning you see above.

Row 4 had 18 backslashes, so there is no problem, and shows up as 9 backslahes because each was escaped.  Had there been an odd number, the error on row 2 would have happened to row 4.

The bonus characters on row 5 came through normally. Everything is allowed except tab.

**Step 7, reset table penguin:**

```
mysql> delete from penguin;
```

**Step 8, load into your table with the `fields escaped by` clause:**

```
mysql> load data local infile '/home/el/foo/textfile.txt' into table penguin 
       fields terminated by '\t' escaped by '\b' 
       lines terminated by '\n' (@col1, @col2) set id=@col1, 
       chucknorris=@col2;

Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Step 9, select from your table, interpret the results:**

```
mysql> select * from penguin;
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | chucknorris                                                      |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | spacealiens are on route                                         |
|  2 | scramble the nimitz\                                             |
|  3 | \its species 8472                                                |
|  4 | \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\                                               |
|  5 | Bonus characters:!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]\|}{;'":/.?>,< anything but tab |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And now everything is as we expect.  The backslash at the end of line 2 does not escape the newline.  The backslash before `i` on row 3 doesn't do anything.  The 18 backslashes on row 4 are not escaped.  And the bonus characters come through ok.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code :

```
$yourVariable = addcslashes($_POST["your param"],"\\");
```

for example in my web form i want insert local directory :

```
$localAddress = addcslashes($_POST["localAddress"],"\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone, as I was struggling for a little while with this.  If you are creating your MySQL string in PHP you will need to quadruple escape your backslash, i.e. have 4 backslashes to create two in your SQL statement.

e.g. php

```
$sqlquery="insert into images (image_path) values (\"\\\\images\\\\cars\\\\sportscars\\\\" . $image_name . ".jpg\");";
```