# Why does a backward slash get dropped when running a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

```
select * from files where filename=\'this.txt\''
```

I looked at [MySQL is not inserting a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770704/mysql-is-not-inserting-a-backslash) and couldn't see the the exact reason why `\` was being dropped.

Long story short (I know the security implications...) the above is stored in a cell. The contents of the cell then gets executed. My question is why isn't there an issue with the backward slashes being present?

In short, why does this work when I would have thought the correct way would be

```
select * from files where filename='this.txt'
```

The PHP comes in how the query is ran

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)
```

Comment: \ is usually an escape character. Have you tried doubling them up? Try `filename ='\\this.txt\\'` instead

Comment: @Takarii You did not understand the question. The question is: "why does this work"...

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What represents the first code fragment? Is it the query that the MySQL server receives? Is it a fragment of your PHP code? It is invalid either way. Please update your question with information that helps the potential responders provide you an answer. And read the [PHP documentation about strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: It doesn't work. The query you've posted is a syntax error; see demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa0b0/2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because its entire premise is wrong; it asks why some syntax is legal, but the syntax *isn't* legal. Presumably what's really going on here is that the query has been copied and pasted from a single-quoted PHP string and the `\'`s are really PHP string escape sequences, but we can't know for sure; without more context all we can do here is psychic debugging.

Comment: You haven't posted enough php code for us to help you, because that language offers a variety of ways to handle string constants, and we can't guess which one you've used. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESCAPE Character is usually  work while put it twice.

if you want to store backward slash then you have escape it by adding on more `\\`.

You will find complete reference here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: So using \'SOMETHING'\ means that when that query is run, it is seen as just 'SOMETHING'??

Comment: yes I know that

Comment: I was asking a question

Comment: yes you are right.If don't want manual esacpe then