# Backslash is being deleted from JSON string when uploaded to DB

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a JSON object, which I have converted into a JSON string using the JSON.stringify() method in JavaScript. I then insert this into the database using AJAX posting to a PHP file.

```
     $("#saveToDatabase").click(function(){
   var place = searchBox.getPlaces();
   var locationJson = JSON.stringify(place[0]);

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insertLocation.php",
    dataType:"json",
    ContentType:"application/json",
    data:  {
      locationJson : locationJson
  },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
     window.alert("successful upload!");
    }});
  });
}

    <?php
require_once("connection.php");



if(isset($_POST["locationJson"])){

    $locationJson = $_POST['locationJson'];

$query ="INSERT INTO Locations (json) VALUES ('$locationJson')";
        $statement = $pdo ->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();

}

?>
```

The problem I am having is that at somepoint as the data is being uploaded, the backslash "\" is being removed from my JSON strings. So when I select them from the database and  try to manipulate them again in JavaScript, they are no longer valid JSON objects.

I am using SQL to upload to PHPmyAdmin.

Does anyone know a way around this? I need to store my JSON strings on the database without them being invalidated.

Cheers!

Comment: A few things: 1. PHPMyAdmin lets you admin mysql, but you wouldn't _"upload to PHPMyAdmin"_.  Are you using MySQL? Or another SQL language?  Also, would be helpful to see: a. The string immediately before you insert, b. The string as it sits in the db, then c. The string after you request it....

Comment: Beware of sql injection :) You could use `$locationJson = json_encode($_POST['locationJson']);`

Comment: Maybe duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770704/mysql-is-not-inserting-a-backslash

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"` is wrong. `$.ajax` sends URL-encoded data. The only JSON is `locationJson` because you called `JSON.stringify()` to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parametrized query instead of substituting the variable into the string.

```
$query ="INSERT INTO Locations (json) VALUES (:json)";
$statement = $pdo ->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(':json', $locationJson);
$statement->execute();
```

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for explanations about why substituting variables into SQL queries is a bad idea, even if you use functions like `addslashes()` to try to escape them.

Comment: Does perform an "add slashes" that would escape the backslashes and solve OP's problem? Or is it just an improvement to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: @cale_b `$pdo->quote($locationJson)` would be better than `addslashes()`, but parameters are universally considered the best way.

Comment: Thanks! That helps! (And, part of what I was driving at is it might be nice to add a note to the answer to clarify that aspect.... )

Comment: I've added a link to the canonical dupe about SQL injection.

Comment: This fixed the problem for JSON string insertion into the database, however when I select them from the DB - it seems to be removing the backslashes once again!


Can you point me in the right direction?

`function getMarkers(){
    global $pdo;

$query ="SELECT json FROM Locations";
$statement = $pdo ->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$markers = $statement->fetchall();
return $markers;
}`

Comment: That code doesn't remove the backslashes. It must be happening when you use `$markers` later.

Comment: The plot thickens... I believe I have found the perpetrator:
`$markerArray = getMarkers();
$firstLocation = $markerArray[0];

$firstLocation = implode("", $firstLocation);`

I think the implode is messing me up - however If I dont implode, then the value of $firstLocation is just "Array".

Comment: Why are you using JSON in the first place? What is `place[0]`?

Comment: You should use `$firstLocation = json_decode($markerArray[0]['json'], true);`. Then `$firstLocation` will be a PHP array if `place[0]` was a Javascript object or array.

Comment: `fetchAll()` returns a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @Barmar each JSON string represents information about a location on a map. I will be able to use the details from each JSON string in the array to place a marker on the map.

Comment: So `place[0]` is an object? Use `var_dump($firstLocation);` after my above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172791/discussion-between-viktor-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to fix escape eaters.  I've found when I store JSON strings, I inevitably end up dealing with the same problems later on.  Since I never search stored objects in SQL, I generally just convert them to base64.  So:

```
btoa(JSON.stringify(place[0]))
```

Sadly, some base64 characters cause issues in URL's, filenames, etc., so I actually use a modified base64 for URL's.  In javascript:

```
function safeobj(ob) {
    return btoa(JSON.stringify(ob)).replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=/g, ".");
}
```

This pretty much gets through anything unscathed.  For me, its worth the bit of extra storage to avoid constantly dealing with these various issues.

If you are supporting IE9-, you will need a shim or polyfill for btoa.